# Calling external javascript from HTML button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set up a page that calls an external Javascript function when the user presses a button in an html form. The function name is lock(), and my code for the button is as follows:

```
<form>
<button type="button" onclick="lock()">Pause/Play</button>
</form>
```

Trying to run the code gives the following error:

```
The value of the property 'lock' is null or undefined, not a Function object
```

I have confirmed that the function I'm trying to call is a global one in the scope of the .js file, and I know that the .js file is being loaded when the page starts because all of the functionality except for this button works. Am I missing any obvious steps and, if not, what do I need to verify? Thanks.

Comment: If there's an error in your globally executed code, it could prevent the function from being created. Any errors in the console on page load?

Comment: Please post your inclusion script. If `lock()` is called before you include the script, it doesn't exist.

Comment: ...though that error message makes it sound like `lock` should be the property of an object. Is this your actual code?

Comment: Go into the developer console and type your function name. If it returns "undefined", you know that it hasn't loaded into the global space for whatever reason (possibly a typo, or an error before its definition as has been mentioned...)

Answer (score 0):

if you open up dev tools, such as f12 in chrome, and enter lock in console, does it return the function? or undefined?

its impossible ot tell whats going on without seeing your code.

a few things you can try:

1.Include the script tag right above the closing tag of the body, to ensure that the script is loaded after the button.

1. Attach the event handler to the button not inline, but in the domcontentloaded event.
2. to debug, try calling some other function from same button, to islotate the problem, and vice versa, try attaching the function to a different button, see if it works there.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Lock() came up undefined when I entered it in the console. The javascript I'm trying to call the function from is rather long, so I've pastebinned it here: http://pastebin.com/DKb38QbL

Comment: you need to check just 'lock', not 'lock()'   if lock returns undefined, then 'lock()' in console will execute function and return undefined. 'lock' returns the code of the function itself.

Comment: Ah, okay. Unfortunately, "lock" came up undefined too.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you have the javascript line in your html that calls the function from other source?  If you had that plotted inside `<head></head>`, then try move the line way further to below in your html file like right before `</body>` like as for example:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>My HTML</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <blah></blah>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="myexternal.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```